# Calculating $\mathbf{B,E}$ for electric dipole field radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, dipole

I tried to read posts regarding this question, but I only found ones with different notations which I didn't understand.

I'm trying to calculate

$$\mathbf{B(x,}t)=\nabla \times \mathbf{A(x},t)=\nabla \times \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r } e^{-i\omega(t-\frac{r}{c})} (-i \omega \mathbf{p}_\omega),$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is the vector potential, and $\mathbf{p}_\omega$ is the dipole moment. This is from Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, section 9.2.

My approach to this is:

$$\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_j  \bigg(\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r } e^{-i\omega\big(t-\frac{r}{c}\big)} (-i \omega \mathbf{p}_\omega)\bigg)_k =\varepsilon_{ijk} \frac{\mu_0 }{4\pi r} \frac{i\omega}{c} e^{-i\omega\big(t-\frac{r}{c}\big)} \cdot \partial_j \big(-\frac{r}{c}\big)\cdot (-i\omega  \mathbf{p}_\omega),$$

where I only differentiated the exponential because we don't keep the $\dfrac{1}{r^2}$ part.

But in the book the answer is:

$$\mathbf{B(x},t)=\frac{\mu}{4\pi r}\frac{\omega^2}{c}e^{-i\omega\big(t-\frac{r}{c}\big)} (\hat{x}\times \mathbf{p}_\omega).$$

I can understand how we only differentiate the exponent. I can also see where the cross product comes from (i.e., because $\nabla r=\nabla |\mathbf{x}|=\hat{x}$), but I miss a factor of $\dfrac{1}{c}$ in the derivation. And why isn't $\partial_j \mathbf{p}_\omega $ being considered here?

Answer (score 1):

Should be $\partial_j r$ instead of $\partial_j \left(-\frac{r}{c}\right)$. You already used the $\frac{i\omega}{c}$. Then you get what the book does. $\partial_j p=0$ because the dipole moment does not depend on the position where we are evaluating the field, it's a constant.

Comment: But $\dfrac{i\omega}{c}$ comes from once differentiating the exponential part, then i differentiate the inner part: $(t-\dfrac{r}{c})$ which also gives $\partial_{j} \dfrac{-r}{c}$

Comment: If that's the inner part, then instead of the $\frac{i \omega}{c}$ it should be $-i\omega$.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answer. I should probably take a break from studying :)